# Is it possible for dynamic data to share one state without updating all of them with same content?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dynamic, react-hooks, e-commerce

I am trying to update my data dynamically only on frontend. I am having list of objects and I am mapping through them.

To be more specific, I have some chairs as my products and different chair has different color variants.

If I click on chair n. 1, it will be selected and chair variants will be shown, this should be changed when chair n.2 is clicked.

```
 const ProductsData = Object.values(products).map((data) => {
        return (
            <>
                <div className="box" onMouseEnter={() => setSelectedData(data)}>
                    <img src={data.image} />
                        <Row>
                            <h1>{data.name}</h1>
                        </Row>
                    </div>
            </>
        );
    });
```

And data of selected chair:

```
<div className="container">
     {ProductsData}
</div>
```

and showing different variants of chair colors

```
 {selectedData ? ( 

   {selectedData.name}

   {selectedColor && <img src={selectedColor.image} alt="chair" />}

          {Object.values(selectedData.chair.colors).map((val) => {
               return <div onClick={() => setSelectedColor(val)}>{val.name}</div>;
          })}
)}
```

Here is created sandbox for easier understanding: https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-meninsky-ypjmr?file=/src/App.js:3483-3708

**Issues that needs to be solved:**

1. Clicking on ONE should show default image, right now user has to click on color variant to show the image. -> When clicking on TWO, image should get updated with default image of TWO, right now image still stays from ONE until color variant of TWO is clicked.
2. In summary `listItemsInCart()` both options ONE and TWO are having the same image, even though each of the option should have its own image of the color variants that has been picked.

Is it possible to achieve this with sharing one state?

```
 const [selectedData, setSelectedData] = React.useState();
 const [selectedColor, setSelectedColor] = React.useState();
```

Answer (score 0):

To select the default color upon choosing item, change onClick handler like this:

```
onClick={() => {
  setSelectedData(data);
  setSelectedColor(Object.values(data.chair.colors)[0]);
}
```

Colors should ideally be an array since every item will have same structure, then it'd be:

```
setSelectedColor(data.chair.colors[0]);
```

Comment: that makes sense @bgcodes, thanks! But I am still having issue in my chosen product summary, all images are the same even though they are different products. Do you know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is not super clear to me what you are asking for on the second issue but from looking at your code, it looks like you are adding an item onto the cart but item has got both colors. I think the added data should be a separate object like this:
{ item: item, color: 'red', quantity: 1}

Comment: If you look into sandbox I shared in post, on the bottom of the page is small summary of products - they both have the same image, even though they shouldn't have. They are 2 individual products with specific images.